# Finding the functional equation

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I'm reading through Silverman's Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves and am reading about the functional equation of the $L$-series attached to CM elliptic curves. I understand that the functional equation of non-CM elliptic curves is the same (is it?), but I can't seem to find the material in the book. Is there something I can refer to about this?

Also, what can we do with $L$-series of elliptic surfaces?

Comment: Please give an example of such $L$-series in your question to establish a clear context. Did you do a web search already?

Comment: The $L$-series of non-CM elliptic curves is defined in the same way. The functional equation is *conjecturally* the same. This is Conjecture 10.2 in Silverman. However, except when $E$ is an elliptic curve over a CM field, the existence of analytic continuation and functional equation is still a conjecture (and even then, we only know meromorphic continuation). When $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$, analytic continuation follows from the modularity theorem!!

Comment: @Somos I don't understand your comment. The $L$-series is a standard object for anyone working with elliptic curves, so the context is crystal clear. Anyone in doubt can check the (very standard) reference of Silverman's book. The OP has provided ample context to their question, in terms of a specific book reference. This question is not one that would be easily answered with a Google search.